# Dynamic content view within UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to put a view that displays comments within my `UITableViewCell`, created with storyboards. That view is sized based on the number of comments to display and the size of each comment body. The view is set up in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method with a call to this function:

```
-(void)setupWithComments:(NSArray*)comments count:(int)count {
    int commentsToDisplay = comments.count;

    if (commentsToDisplay == 0) {
        return;
    }

    CGFloat yValue = 0;
    for (int i = commentsToDisplay - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        PComment *comment = [comments objectAtIndex:i];

        UIView *containerBlock = [[UIView alloc] init];

        UILabel *timeAgoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        timeAgoLabel.text = [PUtilities timeAgo:comment.createdAt];
        timeAgoLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        timeAgoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        timeAgoLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [containerBlock addSubview:timeAgoLabel];

        [timeAgoLabel makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.bottom.equalTo(containerBlock.bottom).with.offset(-10);
            make.right.equalTo(containerBlock.right).with.offset(-10);
        }];

        NSAttributedString *commentString = [PUtilities attributeSubstrings:@[comment.formattedBody, comment.creator.username]
                                                             withAttributes:@[CommentBodyAttributes, UsernameAttributes]
                                                             inFormatString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@", comment.creator.username, comment.formattedBody]];

        CGRect commentSize = [comment.attributedBody boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(270, 9999)
                                                         options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                         context:nil];

        UILabel *commentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        commentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        commentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        commentLabel.attributedText = commentString;
        commentLabel.tag = (i + 1);

        [containerBlock addSubview:commentLabel];

        [commentLabel makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.left.equalTo(containerBlock.left).with.offset(25);
            make.top.equalTo(containerBlock.top).with.offset(10);
            make.right.equalTo(containerBlock.right).with.offset(-25);
        }];

        CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(commentSize) + 20;
        containerBlock.frame = CGRectMake(0, yValue, 320, height);
        yValue += height;

        [PUtilities logFrame:containerBlock.frame];

        [self addSubview:containerBlock];
    }
}
```

The challenge is getting the table view cell to be the correct size. By default, they are supposed to be the size of the frame, minus the status bar (548). I attempt to get the correct height for the cells with this method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *CommentBodyAttributes = @{
                                            NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0],
                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]
                                            };

    PVideo *video = [self.videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    if (video.mostRecentComments.count != 0) {

        __block CGFloat height = 0;
        [video.mostRecentComments enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PComment *comment, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            NSAttributedString *commentString = [PUtilities attributeSubstrings:@[comment.formattedBody, comment.creator.username]
                                                                 withAttributes:@[CommentBodyAttributes, CommentBodyAttributes]
                                                                 inFormatString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@", comment.creator.username, [comment formattedBody]]];

            CGRect commentSize = [commentString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(270, 9999)
                                                             options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                             context:nil];
            height += CGRectGetHeight(commentSize) + 20;
        }];

        NSLog(@"%f", height + 457);

        return 457 + height;
    }else {
        return kVideoCellHeight;
    }
}
```

But it never sizes appropriately, resulting in comments either being cut off, or excess space at the bottom. Are there any obvious mistakes in the code that I'm just missing?

Comment: Is the UITableViewCell the correct size and just the label the wrong size or is the UITableViewCell the wrong size?

Comment: The UITableViewCell is cutting off the lower part of the last label